# Checkbox list not rendered at Table in IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11, checkboxlist

I use RepeatLayout="Table" property of checkboxlist but still it is rendered with span rather than table on IE11. It works perfectly till ie10 and on other browsers.

I am working on this issue from a long time as still not able to find any solutions. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show us you code?

Answer (score 1):

Found resolution at below link
http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11